# Changing array index in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have a fits image. It has an array dimension of 300 x 8500. When I plot the image, it shows the y-axis range from 0 to 300, x-axis range from 0 to 8500. If I want to change the x-axis to 1385.9--1213.9, how do you do it in python? I don't want to change the data value just the index. Currently, after reading in the fits file, I do

```
data_a=[:,:]

implot= plt.imshow(data_a,cmap=plt.cm.afmhot,interpolation='nearest',aspect='auto',origin='lower')
```

I would think something like the `index = 1385.9 - numpy.arange(0,8500,1)*0.02`, will do but only interger or boolean is allowed for index.

Comment: `index` is not a property of the data array; it is just a way of counting rows and columns.

Comment: Any progress? ... did the answer below help?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
implot= plt.imshow(data_a,cmap=plt.cm.afmhot,
            interpolation='nearest',aspect='auto',origin='lower',
            extent=[1385.9,-1213.9,0,300])
```

`extent` adjusts the `x` and `y` labeling according to the edge values in

```
extent = [horizontal_min,horizontal_max,vertical_min,vertical_max]
```

Comment: thank you. Yes. it did. Sorry, I know that this is an old thread (long time ago). I forgot to reply.